# Loop creates unwanted duplicate

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am trying to pull in data from an input file and iterate over a symbol file to create output for an output file but my code is creating an unwanted duplicate in the output file.  The input file is very big so I need to filter the input first before I reference it against the symbol (city/state) file to generate the output.

```
i_file = ('InputFile.csv')
o_file = ('OutputFile.csv')
symbol_file = ('SymbolFile.csv')
City = 'Tampa'
State = 'FL'

with open(symbol_file, 'r') as symfile:
    with open(i_file, 'r') as infile:
        with open(o_file, 'w') as outfile:

            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            symbol = csv.reader(symfile)
            writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ',')

            for row in reader:
                if (row[2] == city and row[3] == state):

                   for line in symbol:
                        if (row[4] == line[0]):
                            nline = ([str(city)] + [str(line[3])])
                            writer.writerow(nline)
                    symfile.seek(0)
```

Comment: `for line in symbolreader`: What is symbolreader ?

Comment: are you sure that it is the loop that is causing the duplicate and not the input files in some way ?

Comment: Sharad - that was a typo.  Ev. Kounis - the input file is not duplicated.

Comment: can you also post a sample of the two input files ? Two or three lines of each or so.. Also, the writing takes place under the `if (row[2] == city and row[3] == state):` loop. Therefore, duplicate values in the output file mean that the statement above evaluates to `True` at least twice.

Comment: This creates a line for every match between the input file and the symbol file. You probably only want one line for every line in the input file *IF* there is a matching line in the symbol file?

Comment: poke - yes, I only want one line for every line in the input file IF there is a matching line in the symbol file.

Comment: As an aside, an you are reading your symbol file in its entirety for every filtered line in your input file, it would make sense to read it once into a list of lists and then simply iterate over that, rather than repeatedly reading and seeking.

Answer (score 0):

> I only want one line for every line in the input file IF there is a matching line in the symbol file.

Try it like this then:

```
i_file = 'InputFile.csv'
o_file = 'OutputFile.csv'
symbol_file = 'SymbolFile.csv'

city = 'Tampa'
state = 'FL'

# load the symbols from the symbol file and store them in a dictionary
symbols = {}
with open(symbol_file, 'r') as symfile:
    for line in csv.reader(symfile):
        # key is line[0] which is the thing we match against
        # value is line[3] which appears to be the only thing of interest later
        symbols[line[0]] = line[3]

# now read the other files
with open(i_file, 'r') as infile, open(o_file, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = ',')

    for row in reader:
        # check if `row[4] in symbols`
        # which essentially checks whether row[4] is equal to a line[0] in the symbols file
        if row[2] == city and row[3] == state and row[4] in symbols:
            # get the symbol
            symbol = symbols[row[4]]

            # write output
            nline = [city, symbol]
            writer.writerow(nline)
```